# Filter by Age in EFCore using Postgresql - Npgsql

Tags: entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

Is it possible to translate this following Postgresql query to EFCore?

```
SELECT "applic"."age" FROM (
   SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(birthdate)) :: int AS "age" FROM public.applicant
) AS "applic"
WHERE "applic"."age" < 50;
```

I've looked into the documents but I can't find anything helpful.

Comment: A good start would be to try something and show us what you did and where how it didn't succeed (if it didn't). Only then can we see where *specifically* you need help.

Comment: @GertArnold I posted a solution that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works:

```
var applicants = from s in this.RepositoryContext.Applicants select s;

if (query.AgeStart != null && query.AgeEnd != null)
{
    applicants = applicants.Where(c => (DateTime.Today.Year - c.BirthDate.Year) >= query.AgeStart && (DateTime.Today.Year - c.BirthDate.Year) < query.AgeEnd);
}
```